# why sourcetree are always showing remote branches?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

On a recent update, sourcetree now are always showing remote branches on my tree graph (named as origin/remote-branch-name, as supposed to be).

Before this update, I could hide remote branches and see only locals and "cloned" branches.

Can I change it? I already researched the settings and did not find.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Which version of SourceTree are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest version, 2.6.10, there's a checkbox "Show Remote Branches":

[image]